# Custom WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter

Tags: spring, dependency-injection, spring-security, spring-boot

I have this problem implementing a custom login authentication using SpringBoot and SpringBoot-Security. I made a [Bitbucket repository](https://bitbucket.org/dpebadiola/springbootcustomwebsecurity) as reference for this thread (within [CustomSecuringWeb branch](https://bitbucket.org/dpebadiola/springbootcustomwebsecurity/branch/CustomSecuringWeb)). Before anything else, most of the comments here follows the [Securing a Web Application](https://spring.io/guides/gs/securing-web/) tutorial.

The thing is, I was curious as how could the authentication data is now from the database instead of just memory data (which is very common in production line applications).

Throughout the process I made two attempts (though both attempts are located on the same branch - *my bad for that*).

1. Created a custom `UserDetailsService` implementation
2. Created a custom `AbstractUserDetailsAuthentictionProvider` implementation

I don't know where the problem lies, but upon checking the console log both returns that the persistence(even the repository) DI on each custom class where null.

The question is how could I make both attempts working. And (possibly) which one of the two attempts is better than the other.

Comment: your bitbucket links are dead

Answer (score 11, accepted):

First of all the two approaches are used for different purpose and not interchangeable.

Case 1:

`UserDetailsService` is used purely as DAO to locate user information by your authentication and based on that info authenticate user, no authentication should be done within `UserDetailsService`, just data access.
Specifications clearly mention that. This is what you are looking for.

Case2:

`AuthentictionProvider` on the other hand is used for providing custom method of authentication, for example if you want to custom authenticate on fields other than login and password you may do that by implementing `AuthentictionProvider` and supplying this object to your `AuthenticationManagerBuilder`. I do not think this is what you want to do in you project. You are just looking to implement your authentication based on users stored in database using login and password which is default way.
In above **Case 1** where you implemented just `UserDetailsService`, instance of `AuthentictionProvider` was created for you in `AuthenticationManager` by the container and it was `DaoAuthenticationProvider` since you supplied UserDetailsService which is nothing else but DAO in your system that is used to retrive user for authentication.

Now to your implementation,
in your configuration instead of :

```
  @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
//        auth.userDetailsService(new AdminSecurityService());
        auth.authenticationProvider(new AdminSecurityAuthenticationProvider());
    }
```

do something like this

```
@Autowired
private CustomUserDetailsService userDetailsService;

 @Override
protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
    auth.userDetailsService(userDetailsService);

}
```

and your `CustomUserDetailsService` has to implement `org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetailsService`

```
@Service
public class CustomUserDetailsService implements UserDetailsService {

    private final AdminRepository userRepository;

    @Autowired
    public CustomUserDetailsService(AdminRepository userRepository) {
        this.userRepository = userRepository;
    }

    @Override
    public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String username) throws UsernameNotFoundException {
        Admin user = userRepository.findByLogin(username);
        if (user == null) {
            throw new UsernameNotFoundException(String.format("User %s does not exist!", username));
        }
        return new UserRepositoryUserDetails(user);
    }

    private final static class UserRepositoryUserDetails extends Admin implements UserDetails {

        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

        private UserRepositoryUserDetails(User user) {
            super(user);
        }

        @Override
        public Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> getAuthorities() {
            return AuthorityUtils.createAuthorityList("ROLE_USER");
        }

        @Override
        public String getUsername() {
            return getLogin();//inherited from user
        }

        @Override
        public boolean isAccountNonExpired() {
            return true;//not for production just to show concept
        }

        @Override
        public boolean isAccountNonLocked() {
            return true;//not for production just to show concept
        }

        @Override
        public boolean isCredentialsNonExpired() {
            return true;//not for production just to show concept
        }

        @Override
        public boolean isEnabled() {
            return true;//not for production just to show concept
        }
//getPassword() is already implemented in User.class
    }

}
```

of course implementation is up to you but you have to be able to provide user password, and rest of the methods in that interface based on the retrieved user (Admin.class in your case). Hope it helps. I did not run this example so if I made some typos go ahead and ask if something does not work. I would also get rid of that 'AuthentictionProvider' from your project if you don't need it.

Here you got documentation:http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/4.0.0.RC1/reference/htmlsingle/#tech-userdetailsservice

**After comments:**
You can set `PasswordEncoder` in your configure method without too much hassle just do:

```
 @Override
protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
    auth.userDetailsService(userDetailsService).passwordEncoder(passwordEncoder);

    }
@Bean
    public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder(){
        PasswordEncoder encoder = new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
        return encoder;
    }
```

You can do that because you get access to `AbstractDaoAuthenticationConfigurer` returned from `auth.userDetailsService(userDetailsService)` and it allows you to configure `DaoAuthenticationProvider`, which is your provider of choice when you choose to use `UserDetailsService`. 
You are right `PasswordEncoder` is set in `AuthenticationProvider` but you do not have to 
implement `AuthenticationProvider` just use convineince object that is returned from `auth.userDetailsService(userDetailsService)` and set your encoder on that object which will pass it to `AuthenticationPriovider` in your case `DaoAuthenticationProvider` that was already created for you. 
Just like roadrunner mentioned in the comment you very rarely need to implement your own `AuthenticationProvider` usually most of authentication configuration adjustments can be done with the use of `AbstractDaoAuthenticationConfigurer` which as mentioned above is returned from `auth.userDetailsService(userDetailsService)`.

"And if I ever wanted to add a password encryption. And if I ever wanted to do other authentication (like checking if the user is locked, active, user is still logged-in, etc. [excluding password hashing]) will use the AuthenticationProvider."

No this is done for you as part of standard authentication mechanism
http://docs.spring.io/autorepo/docs/spring-security/3.2.0.RELEASE/apidocs/org/springframework/security/core/userdetails/UserDetails.html
If you look at the interface `UserDetails` you will see that if any of the above methods returns false authentication will fail. 
Implementing `AuthenticationProvider` is really needed in very nonstandard cases. All standard stuff is pretty much covered by the framework .

Comment: I see. Basically use `UserDetailsService` to retrieve the user details using the `username` parameter. And if I ever wanted to add a password encryption. And if I ever wanted to do other authentication (like checking if the user is locked, active, user is still logged-in, etc. [excluding password hashing]) will use the `AuthenticationProvider`.

Comment: And if I ever wanted to have a password encryption, I'll just create a custom `PasswordEncoder` instance then include it in either cases, right?

Comment: No. There are very good implementations of both `AuthenticationProvider` and `PsswordEncoder` interfaces already available in Spring Security. You should *not* implement them on your own in 99% of cases. Also, this seems out of scope of original question. Please read referenced documentation or ask another question.

Answer (score 1):

In a JDBC way http://www.mkyong.com/spring-security/spring-security-form-login-using-database/ basically, you have to specify the query to retrieve users.

Comment: This can be a quick solution. But what if I wanted to create a custom password encoder for all password related fields.

Comment: The PasswordEncoder is responsible of encoding/decoding passwords. The encoder can be specified on the DAO with this method: _auth.jdbcAuthentication().dataSource(dataSource).passwordEncoder()_;

Comment: But what if I wanted to create a custom authentication aside from jdbcAuthentication (i.e., SessionAuthentication - check if the user is still logged-in, etc.)?

Comment: Following the [single responsibility principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle) you should not handle session storage in your `AuthenticationProvider`. Spring Security has other mechanisms to deal with it and it is an out of the box feature that is enabled by default and can be disabled if not needed.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly I would encourage you to read about [String Security Core Services](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/3.2.5.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/#core-services).

A key one in this situation is [`AuthenticationManager`](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/blob/master/core/src/main/java/org/springframework/security/authentication/AuthenticationManager.java) that is responsible for deciding if the user is authenticated or not. This is what you configure with `AuthenticationManagerBuilder`. It's primary implementation in Spring is [`ProviderManager`](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/blob/master/core/src/main/java/org/springframework/security/authentication/ProviderManager.java) that allows to define multiple authentication mechanisms in a single applications. The most common use case is that there is one, but it is still handled by this class. Each of those multiple authentication mechanisms is represented by a different [`AuthenticationProvider`](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/blob/master/core/src/main/java/org/springframework/security/authentication/AuthenticationProvider.java). `ProviderManager` takes a list of `AunthenticationProviders` an iterates through them to see if any of them can authenticate the user.

What you are interested in is [`DaoAuthenticationProvider`](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/blob/master/core/src/main/java/org/springframework/security/authentication/dao/DaoAuthenticationProvider.java). As the name suggests, it allows to use a Data Access Object to authenticate the user. It uses a standard interface for such DAO - a [`UserDetailsService`](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/blob/master/core/src/main/java/org/springframework/security/core/userdetails/UserDetailsService.java). There is a default implementation available in Spring Security, but usually this is the bit you will want to implement yourself. All the rest is provided.

Also, the configuration bit you need is totally independent from Spring Boot. This is how you'd do it in XML:

```
<sec:authentication-manager >
    <sec:authentication-provider user-service-ref="myUserDetailsService" />
</sec:authentication-manager>
```

And in Java it will be:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class WebSecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    private UserDetailsService myUserDetailsService;

    @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.userDetailsService(myUserDetailsService);
    }
}
```

As per [`UserDetails`](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/blob/master/core/src/main/java/org/springframework/security/core/userdetails/UserDetails.java) implementation, usually [the one provided by Spring Security](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/blob/master/core/src/main/java/org/springframework/security/core/userdetails/User.java) is enough. But you can also implement your own if need be.

Usually you will also want a [`PasswordEncoder`](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/blob/master/core/src/main/java/org/springframework/security/authentication/encoding/PasswordEncoder.java). A good one, like [`BCryptPasswordEncoder`](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/blob/master/crypto/src/main/java/org/springframework/security/crypto/bcrypt/BCryptPasswordEncoder.java):

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class WebSecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    private UserDetailsService userDetailsService;

    @Autowired
    private PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder;

    @Bean
    public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.userDetailsService(userDetailsService)
            .passwordEncoder(passwordEncoder);
    }
}
```

Notice that it's a `@Bean`, so that you can `@Autowire` it in your `UserRepository` to encode user passwords as you save them in the database.

Comment: Is there a way to remove the XML configuration?

Comment: It's an alternative. You can do it either in XML or in Java. I showed both ways. You don't do both at once - just one of them.